# Rails 3: sunspot solr : adding search ability for every page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search, solr, sunspot

How do you add search to a layout so it can search for posts through every page of the site? such as here on stackoverflow.

Tutorials show adding the search method to the index action of the PostsController, and then adding the form and results block in views/post/index.html.erb.

I've been trying to create a form in application.html.erb that sends a get request to the search action of the posts controller. I can't seem to get it right, can someone help explain where I'm going wrong?

Currently I'm getting this error when going to my homepage:

NameError in Pages#home

undefined local variable or method `search_posts_path'

### PostsController

```
   def search
     if params[:q]
       query = params[:q]
       @search = Post.search do
         keywords query
       end
       @posts = @search.results
     end
    end
```

### post model

```
 searchable do
       text :title, :default_boost => 2
       text :content
  end
```

### routes.rb

```
  match 'auth/:provider/callback' => 'authentications#create'
  resources :authentications

  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => 'registrations'}




  resources :posts do
      member do
      get :likers, :search
      end
  end  

  resources :relationships, :only => [:create, :destroy]
  resources :appreciations, :only => [:create, :destroy]

  root :to => "pages#home"

 match '/contact', :to => 'pages#contact'
 match '/about',   :to => 'pages#about'
 match '/help',    :to => 'pages#help'
 match '/blog',    :to => 'pages#blog'


  resources :users do
     member do
     get :following, :followers, :likes
     end
     resources :collections
  end
```

### views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag search_posts_path, :method => :get do %>
<p>
<%= text_field_tag :q, params[:q] %> <%= submit_tag "Search!" %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

### PagesController

```
 def home
    @title = "Home"
    if user_signed_in?
      @user = current_user
      @post = current_user.posts.build
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(:per_page => "10", :page => params[:page])
    else
     #render :layout => 'special_layout' 
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Ruby on Rails routing question.

The `member` route is for operating on a single record. So you are defining `search_post_path(@post)` which will route to something like `/posts/1/search`

What you want is a `collection` route.

```
resources :posts do
  member do
    get :likers
  end
  collection do
    get :search
  end
end
```

This will create the `search_posts_path` method and route to `/posts/search` as you are expecting.

See also: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

Comment: I am trying the exact steps but get this error "Couldn't find Post with id=search". Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Arko, the `collection` isn't being registered correctly, and Rails is defaulting to the `show` action on the `:posts` resource instead. Keep trying :)