# Sunspot solr search works only from one page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, search, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I am following the instructions mentioned here [Rails 3: sunspot solr : adding search ability for every page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005766/rails-3-sunspot-solr-adding-search-ability-for-every-page)

However it does not seem to work for me. I'm trying to implement a twitter like search functionality where the search bar stays at the top in the navigation bar and one can make a search through any page within in the application and it takes them to the search result page.

When I pass the search query in the browser while in the homepage of posts (views/posts/index.html.erb)

```
http://localhost:3000/post?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=test&commit=Search
```

It returns  desired search results. But when I'm in some other page of the application and try to search it forms urls in the address bar like the ones mentioned below and never goes to the search through the search box in the top navigation bar declared in the views/layouts/application.html.erb  page.

```
http://localhost:3000/users/1/following?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=test&commit=Search

http://localhost:3000/posts/1/favorite?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=test&commit=Search
```

Here are the details :-

My model 
**post.rb**

```
searchable do
    text :title, :tag_list 
  end
```

My Controller - **posts_controller.rb**

```
def index


      if params[:search]

        @search = Post.search do
          fulltext params[:search]
          paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 5        
        end

        @posts = @search.results
      else

              @posts = @posts.plusminus_tally({:order => "vote_count ASC"}).page(params[:page]).per(6)   

       end

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html 
        format.json { render json: @posts}
      end
  end
```

View - **layouts/application.rb**

```
 <%= form_tag posts_path, :method => :get do %>
                    <div class="input-append">
                      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] , :class => "span2 search-query", :style => 'width:200px' %>
                      <%= submit_tag "Search", :post => nil , :class => "btn" %>
                    </div>  
                  <% end %>
```

Comment: You may want to take a look at this railscasts video - http://railscasts.com/episodes/278-search-with-sunspot

Comment: Thanks David. I have seen this video before and it does not mention the approach to make search accessible across the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out. This needs to be called on every controller of the current page to redirect the search post to its search results page (in this case Posts#index)

**Favorite controller**  & **User Controller**

```
 if params[:search]
             search_param = CGI::escapeHTML(params[:search])    

             redirect_to ("/posts?search=#{search_param}&commit=Search") 

            return
       end
```